Is this expression from Dirac Field wrong in P&S?
Im going through Peskin and Shroeder's book on QFT, in the chapter about the Dirac Equation, in equation 3.87. They are trying to teach why quantizing with the commutator is wrong, and I'm trying to follow the calculations. When it comes to the expression of the commutator itself:
$$\psi(\mathbf{x}) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\mathbf{p}}}} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} \sum_{s=1,2} \left( a_{\mathbf{p}}^s u^s(\mathbf{p}) + b_{-\mathbf{p}}^s v^s(-\mathbf{p}) \right)$$
where $a_{\mathbf{p}}^s$ and $b_{\mathbf{p}}^s$ are operator coefficients. However, shouldn't the quantity be $b_{\mathbf{-p}}^{s\dagger}$, as was the case in the Klein-Gordon Field?

You are correct that it should be a creation operator. I'm not sure about the sign of $\textbf{p}$, but in my lectures, we always used $+\textbf{p}$ for both the creation and annihilation operators, and things worked out perfectly fine.

You should state which page and equation number so people can find the formula with the context needed to answer by the way.

Note that this expression is specifically to show how NOT to do the quantization. The correct expressions are provided later on in the chapter.
